# Given that $\log_a 2 \approx 0.643, \log_a 3 \approx 1.099, and \log_a 5 \approx 1.608$, find $\log_a (120a^2)$ .

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm doing online school due to the virus, and it's late, so I can't ask my teacher for help on this question. I'm trying to get this done tonight.

Given that $\log_a 2 \approx 0.643, \log_a 3 \approx 1.099, and \log_a 5 \approx 1.608$, find $\log_a (120a^2)$ .

I don't know where to start with this! :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What do you know about laws of logarithms?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$\log_a (xy) = \log_a x + \log_a y \space\space \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^+$

And, $\log_a a=1$.